# React detailslist is always empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I am trying to use the following react office ui component:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist

so I have a webpart with the component, but I have 2 issues:

1. First time the webpart loads, the list has not been selected, so it should open the property page but its not opening, thats why I had to do a small trick: which I dont like at all

> ```
>  public render(): void {
>     const element: React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps > = React.createElement(
>       FactoryMethod,
>       {
>         spHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
>         siteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
>         listName: this._dataProvider.selectedList === undefined ? "GenericList" : this._dataProvider.selectedList.Title,
>         dataProvider: this._dataProvider,
>         configureStartCallback: this.openPropertyPane
>       }
>     );
>
>     //ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
>     this._factorymethodContainerComponent = <FactoryMethod>ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
>
>   }
> ```

2nd Problem is that the readItemsAndSetStatus is not getting called when the user selects another List to render items from, so the state is not getting updated.

the webpart code is as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { Version } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField,
  PropertyPaneDropdown,
  IPropertyPaneDropdownOption,
  IPropertyPaneField,
  PropertyPaneLabel
} from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

import * as strings from "FactoryMethodWebPartStrings";
import FactoryMethod from "./components/FactoryMethod";
import { IFactoryMethodProps } from "./components/IFactoryMethodProps";
import { IFactoryMethodWebPartProps } from "./IFactoryMethodWebPartProps";
import * as lodash from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import List from "./components/models/List";
import { Environment, EnvironmentType } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import IDataProvider from "./components/dataproviders/IDataProvider";
import MockDataProvider from "./test/MockDataProvider";
import SharePointDataProvider from "./components/dataproviders/SharepointDataProvider";

export default class FactoryMethodWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IFactoryMethodWebPartProps> {
  private _dropdownOptions: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption[];
  private _selectedList: List;
  private _disableDropdown: boolean;
  private _dataProvider: IDataProvider;
  private _factorymethodContainerComponent: FactoryMethod;

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.context.statusRenderer.displayLoadingIndicator(this.domElement, "Todo");

    /*
    Create the appropriate data provider depending on where the web part is running.
    The DEBUG flag will ensure the mock data provider is not bundled with the web part when you package the
     solution for distribution, that is, using the --ship flag with the package-solution gulp command.
    */
    if (DEBUG && Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
      this._dataProvider = new MockDataProvider();
    } else {
      this._dataProvider = new SharePointDataProvider();
      this._dataProvider.webPartContext = this.context;
    }

    this.openPropertyPane = this.openPropertyPane.bind(this);

    /*
    Get the list of tasks lists from the current site and populate the property pane dropdown field with the values.
    */
    this.loadLists()
      .then(() => {
        /*
         If a list is already selected, then we would have stored the list Id in the associated web part property.
         So, check to see if we do have a selected list for the web part. If we do, then we set that as the selected list
         in the property pane dropdown field.
        */
        if (this.properties.spListIndex) {
          this.setSelectedList(this.properties.spListIndex.toString());
          this.context.statusRenderer.clearLoadingIndicator(this.domElement);
        }
      });

    return super.onInit();
  }

  // render method of the webpart, actually calls Component
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps > = React.createElement(
      FactoryMethod,
      {
        spHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        siteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
        listName: this._dataProvider.selectedList === undefined ? "GenericList" : this._dataProvider.selectedList.Title,
        dataProvider: this._dataProvider,
        configureStartCallback: this.openPropertyPane
      }
    );

    //ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
    this._factorymethodContainerComponent = <FactoryMethod>ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);

  }

  // loads lists from the site and filld the dropdown.
  private loadLists(): Promise<any> {
    return this._dataProvider.getLists()
      .then((lists: List[]) => {
        // disable dropdown field if there are no results from the server.
        this._disableDropdown = lists.length === 0;
        if (lists.length !== 0) {
          this._dropdownOptions = lists.map((list: List) => {
            return {
              key: list.Id,
              text: list.Title
            };
          });
        }
      });
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse("1.0");
  }

  protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
    /*
    Check the property path to see which property pane feld changed. If the property path matches the dropdown, then we set that list
    as the selected list for the web part.
    */
    if (propertyPath === "spListIndex") {
      this.setSelectedList(newValue);
    }

    /*
    Finally, tell property pane to re-render the web part.
    This is valid for reactive property pane.
    */
    super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);
  }

  // sets the selected list based on the selection from the dropdownlist
  private setSelectedList(value: string): void {
    const selectedIndex: number = lodash.findIndex(this._dropdownOptions,
      (item: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption) => item.key === value
    );

    const selectedDropDownOption: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption = this._dropdownOptions[selectedIndex];

    if (selectedDropDownOption) {
      this._selectedList = {
        Title: selectedDropDownOption.text,
        Id: selectedDropDownOption.key.toString()
      };

      this._dataProvider.selectedList = this._selectedList;
    }
  }


  // we add fields dynamically to the property pane, in this case its only the list field which we will render
  private getGroupFields(): IPropertyPaneField<any>[] {
    const fields: IPropertyPaneField<any>[] = [];

    // we add the options from the dropdownoptions variable that was populated during init to the dropdown here.
    fields.push(PropertyPaneDropdown("spListIndex", {
      label: "Select a list",
      disabled: this._disableDropdown,
      options: this._dropdownOptions
    }));

    /*
    When we do not have any lists returned from the server, we disable the dropdown. If that is the case,
    we also add a label field displaying the appropriate message.
    */
    if (this._disableDropdown) {
      fields.push(PropertyPaneLabel(null, {
        text: "Could not find tasks lists in your site. Create one or more tasks list and then try using the web part."
      }));
    }

    return fields;
  }

  private openPropertyPane(): void {
    this.context.propertyPane.open();
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              /*
              Instead of creating the fields here, we call a method that will return the set of property fields to render.
              */
              groupFields: this.getGroupFields()
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

The component webpart code, ommited code for brevity

```
//#region Imports
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./FactoryMethod.module.scss";
import { IFactoryMethodProps } from "./IFactoryMethodProps";
import {
  IDetailsListItemState,
  IDetailsNewsListItemState,
  IDetailsDirectoryListItemState,
  IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState,
  IFactoryMethodState
} from "./IFactoryMethodState";
import { IListItem } from "./models/IListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { ListItemFactory} from "./ListItemFactory";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import {
  DetailsList,
  DetailsListLayoutMode,
  Selection,
  IColumn
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList";
import { MarqueeSelection } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/MarqueeSelection";
import { autobind } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities";
//#endregion

export default class FactoryMethod extends React.Component<IFactoryMethodProps, IFactoryMethodState> {
  private listItemEntityTypeName: string = undefined;
  private _selection: Selection;

  constructor(props: IFactoryMethodProps, state: any) {
    super(props);
    this.setInitialState();
    this._configureWebPart = this._configureWebPart.bind(this);
  }

  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    this.listItemEntityTypeName = undefined;
    this.setInitialState();
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.readItemsAndSetStatus();
  }

  public setInitialState(): void {
    this.state = {
      type: "ListItem",
      status: this.listNotConfigured(this.props)
        ? "Please configure list in Web Part properties"
        : "Ready",
      DetailsListItemState:{
        columns:[],
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsNewsListItemState:{
        columns:[],
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsDirectoryListItemState:{
        columns:[],
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsAnnouncementListItemState:{
        columns:[],
        items:[]
      },
    };
  }

  private _configureWebPart(): void {
    this.props.configureStartCallback();
  }

  // reusable inline component
  public ListMarqueeSelection = (itemState: {columns: IColumn[], items: IListItem[] }) => (
      <div>
        <MarqueeSelection selection={ this._selection }>
          <DetailsList
            items={ itemState.items }
            columns={ itemState.columns }
            setKey="set"
            layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
            selection={ this._selection }
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={ true }
            compact={ true }>
          </DetailsList>
        </MarqueeSelection>
      </div>
  )

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps> {
      switch(this.props.listName)      {
          case "GenericList":
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.DetailsListItemState.columns} />;
          case "News":
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsNewsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.DetailsNewsListItemState.columns}/>;
          case "Announcements":
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsAnnouncementListItemState.items} columns={this.state.DetailsAnnouncementListItemState.columns}/>;
          case "Directory":
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsDirectoryListItemState.items} columns={this.state.DetailsDirectoryListItemState.columns}/>;
          default:
            return null;
      }
  }

  // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(): void {

    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    const items: IListItem[] = factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName);
    const keyPart: string = this.props.listName === "GenericList" ? "" : this.props.listName;
    if(items != null  )
    {
      // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
      // it should not be required.
      this.setState<keyof {}>({
        status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
        ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
          items,
          columns: [
          ]
        }
      });
    }

  }

  private listNotConfigured(props: IFactoryMethodProps): boolean {
    return props.listName === undefined ||
      props.listName === null ||
      props.listName.length === 0;
  }
}
```

the readitemsandsetstatus apparently is only executed once at the beginning and not when the source changes

Update 1:

Thanks for the person who first answered, based on his answer, I went and researched about lifecycle events and found this nice post:

https://staminaloops.github.io/undefinedisnotafunction/understanding-react/

And based on that and your answer I updated my code like this:

```
//#region Imports
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./FactoryMethod.module.scss";
import  { IFactoryMethodProps } from "./IFactoryMethodProps";
import {
  IDetailsListItemState,
  IDetailsNewsListItemState,
  IDetailsDirectoryListItemState,
  IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState,
  IFactoryMethodState
} from "./IFactoryMethodState";
import { IListItem } from "./models/IListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { ListItemFactory} from "./ListItemFactory";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import {
  DetailsList,
  DetailsListLayoutMode,
  Selection,
  buildColumns,
  IColumn
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList";
import { MarqueeSelection } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/MarqueeSelection";
import { autobind } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//#endregion


export default class FactoryMethod extends React.Component<IFactoryMethodProps, IFactoryMethodState> {
  private _selection: Selection;

  constructor(props: IFactoryMethodProps, state: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  // lifecycle help here: https://staminaloops.github.io/undefinedisnotafunction/understanding-react/

  //#region Mouting events lifecycle
  // the object returned by this method sets the initial value of this.state
  getInitialState(): {}   {
    return {
        type: "GenericList",
        status: this.listNotConfigured(this.props)
          ? "Please configure list in Web Part properties"
          : "Ready",
        columns: [],
        DetailsListItemState:{
          items:[]
        },
        DetailsNewsListItemState:{
          items:[]
        },
        DetailsDirectoryListItemState:{
          items:[]
        },
        DetailsAnnouncementListItemState:{
          items:[]
        },
      };
  }

  // the object returned by this method sets the initial value of this.props
  // if a complex object is returned, it is shared among all component instances
  getDefaultProps(): {}  {
    return {

    };
  }

  // invoked once BEFORE first render
  componentWillMount(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    // calling setState here does not cause a re-render

    this.readItemsAndSetStatus(nextProps);
  }

  // the data returned from render is neither a string nor a DOM node.
  // it's a lightweight description of what the DOM should look like.
  // inspects this.state and this.props and create the markup.
  // when your data changes, the render method is called again.
  // react diff the return value from the previous call to render with
  // the new one, and generate a minimal set of changes to be applied to the DOM.
  public render(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps> {
    this.readItemsAndSetStatus(nextProps);
    switch(this.props.listName) {
        case "GenericList":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns} />;
        case "News":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsNewsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        case "Announcements":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsAnnouncementListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        case "Directory":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsDirectoryListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        default:
          return null;
    }
  }

   // invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately AFTER the initial rendering occurs.
   public componentDidMount(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    // you can access any refs to your children
    // (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation - ReactDOM.findDOMNode). 
    // the componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.
    // if you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks,
    // set timers using setTimeout or setInterval, 
    // or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method.
    this._configureWebPart = this._configureWebPart.bind(this);

    // calling read items does not make any sense here, so I called in the will Mount, is that correct?
    // this.readItemsAndSetStatus(nextProps);
  }

  //#endregion

  //#region Props changes lifecycle events (after a property changes from parent component)
  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    this.readItemsAndSetStatus(nextProps);
  }

  // determines if the render method should run in the subsequent step
  // dalled BEFORE a second render
  // not called for the initial render
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps, nextState: IFactoryMethodProps): boolean {
    // if you want the render method to execute in the next step
    // return true, else return false
      return true;
  }

  // called IMMEDIATELY BEFORE a second render
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps, nextState: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    // you cannot use this.setState() in this method
  }

  // called IMMEDIATELY AFTER a second render
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IFactoryMethodProps, prevState: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    // nothing here yet
  }

  //#endregion

  // called IMMEDIATELY before a component is unmounted from the DOM, No region here, its only one method for that lifecycle
  componentWillUnmount(): void {
    // nothing here yet
  }

  //#region private methods
  private _configureWebPart(): void {
    this.props.configureStartCallback();
  }

  // reusable inline component
  private ListMarqueeSelection = (itemState: {columns: IColumn[], items: IListItem[] }) => (
      <div>
        <MarqueeSelection selection={ this._selection }>
          <DetailsList
            items={ itemState.items }
            columns={ itemState.columns }
            setKey="set"
            layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
            selection={ this._selection }
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={ true }
            compact={ true }>
          </DetailsList>
        </MarqueeSelection>
      </div>
  )

  // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(props: IFactoryMethodProps): void {

    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    factory.getItems(props.spHttpClient, props.siteUrl, props.listName)
    .then((items: IListItem[]) => {
      const keyPart: string = props.listName === "GenericList" ? "" : props.listName;
        // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
        // it should not be required.
        this.setState<keyof {}>({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
          ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
            items
          },
          columns: buildColumns(items)
        });
    });
  }

  private listNotConfigured(props: IFactoryMethodProps): boolean {
    return props.listName === undefined ||
      props.listName === null ||
      props.listName.length === 0;
  }

  //#endregion
}
```

So, now, does it make better sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1>** The callback that you are using to open the property pane is being called in the constructor of the `FactoryMethod` component. This is not a good practise as the constructor should not have any side effects (reference [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)). Instead, call this callback in `componentDidMount` which is a lifecycle method that would only be called once and would be ideal for any code that needs to run just once, after the initial loading of the component. (Refer to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for more information on this method).

**2>** The function `readitemandsetstatus` is executed only once because you call it in `componentDidMount`, which is a life-cycle method which runs only once, when the component is loaded on the page for the first time.

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.readItemsAndSetStatus();
  }
```

In `componentWillReceiveProps` you are calling `setInitialState` which would reset your state every time your component receives any new props. (More information on `componentWillReceiveProps` from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops))

```
public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    this.listItemEntityTypeName = undefined;
    this.setInitialState();
  }
```

This would clear all changes that were done by calling `readitemandsetchanges` in the `componentDidMount` method. Is this what you want? If not, then you should probably call your `readitemandsetstatus` function here so that the state is updated as per the new props being passed in via nextProps.

Since you are going to call the same function `readitemandsetstatus` from `componentDidMount` as well as from `componentWillReceiveProps` you should pass the `props` you want to use in the function as a parameter.

```
private readItemsAndSetStatus(props): void {
...
}
```

This will allow you to pass `this.props` from `compoenentDidMount` and `nextProps` from `componentWillReceiveProps` and use them accordingly, within the function.

Hope this solves your problems.

**Update 1:** Firstly, the link that you have shared as your reference, refers to a very old version of React. I would suggest going through the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and other newer resources (e.g. this video at [Egghead](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-component-lifecycle-mounting-basics)) to clear your concepts. Then you can rework your code and fix any issues that you see.

The following changes can be made in your code:

1. Set your initial state in your constructor. That is what it is there for. Also, any function binding should go in here.
2. Do not hook up lifecycle methods that you are not going to use. Methods like `shouldComponentUpdate` are used for optimizing rendering and should only be used if you have a valid reason for it. Otherwise they may degrade performance. As always, check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) on a method before using it.
3. Do any resource fetches or calback actions in `componentDidMount` and not in `componentWillMount`, so that your component has loaded completely in the DOM before you act on changing it in anyway.

Comment: do I need to call the readItemsAndSetStatus from the render method?

Comment: You should never make any api calls or calls which have any side-effects from the render method. According to the docs, "The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser. If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in componentDidMount() or the other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping render() pure makes components easier to think about." - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

Comment: can you please see Update 1 and let me know what you think? thanks